# AppFog Claims I have used all two service slots when I have none in use

Tags: service, appfog

AppFog claims that I am using both of my available services, when in reality I have deleted the services that were in use. (I had MySQL databases attached to a couple of apps I was using, but when I deleted the apps, I also deleted the services... they just never free'd up for some reason)

Anyone have any suggestions on how I might reclaim those lost services?  It's kinda hard to have apps without services and it won't show me anything to unbind or delete in order to free up those slots.

-Thanks

```
C:\Sites>af info

AppFog Free Your Cloud Edition
For support visit http://support.appfog.com

Target:   https://api.appfog.com (v0.999)
Client:   v0.3.18.12

User:     j****g@gmail.com
Usage:    Memory   (0B of 512.0M total)
          Services (2 of 2 total)
          Apps     (0 of 2 total)

C:\Sites>af services

============== System Services ==============

+------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| Service    | Version | Description                   |
+------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| mongodb    | 1.8     | MongoDB NoSQL store           |
| mongodb2   | 2.4.8   | MongoDB2 NoSQL store          |
| mysql      | 5.1     | MySQL database service        |
| postgresql | 9.1     | PostgreSQL database service   |
| rabbitmq   | 2.4     | RabbitMQ message queue        |
| redis      | 2.2     | Redis key-value store service |
+------------+---------+-------------------------------+

=========== Provisioned Services ============
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to email support@appfog.com and get them to look into it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's the only answer that's possible. The only way to clear the instances is by getting the engineers at Appfog to do it and the only way to do that is by emailing them.

Comment: Actually that was exactly what it came down to.  Support wasn't sure what would cause that count to stay when the service had been deleted but they got me sorted out.